# What resolution .ico files do XP and Vista show on the desktop?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, windows-xp

There's loads of choices for .ico files but I can't see any logic in how Windows chooses which resolution/bit depth to show

Comment: The size that's actually shown depends on user settings and context.  Consider the "Views" menu on Explorer in Vista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are the sizes of icons I bundle, which is the union of all the sizes you may need for XP and Vista depending on the settings the user chooses:

- 16x16
- 22x22
- 24x24
- 32x32
- 40x40
- 48x48
- 64x64
- 96x96
- 128x128
- 256x256

Comment: My system (windows 10) displays windows tray icons at 20x20, so your list  is outdated :)

Comment: I would be nice if this list was supplemented with where the different icons are used? 22x22 and 40x40 are new to me..

Comment: @caesay in my case windows 10 uses the 24x24 if present, I have a icon with 16, 20, 24, 32 (all of them 32 bit) and it displays the 24x24 in the tray icon. I'm using `Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification` I have no idea if it does any kind of modification on the icon before displaying it.

Comment: @Peter: the size windows chooses should depend on your personal DPI settings and display density. On my system if a 20 size is available, it is the first choice. If you have different DPI settings, then windows may prioritize 24.