# .net WPF app crash on startup (Error Reporting Window)

Tags: c#, .net, crash, sql-server-ce, startup

I have a .NET based (WPF) app which crashes on Windows XP Service Pack 3, but runs just fine on Windows 7. I installed .Net Framework Client Profile 4 and Sql Server Compact 3.5 on the client system, but the application crashes immediately and displays the error reporting window.

How can I find more details about this error? I guess it can be a SQL Server CE problem. I am catching all exceptions in the application using try catch clauses, but it doesn't help.

Comment: What versions of .Net do you have installed on both computers?

Comment: .NET Framework Client Profile 4 and Extended!

Comment: Have you checked the event log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be this:  [The Icon property in the Window is crashing the application in Windows XP SP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248596/wpf-the-icon-property-in-the-window-is-crashing-the-application-in-windows-xp-sp)